# Cannot access local webserver from IP

Tags: centos, webserver

Firstly, I started with a fresh install of CentOS 7 [Local IP: 192.168.0.11]
Installed apache,postgresql,php.

Couldn't access the webserver from [Local IP: 192.168.0.10]
Set port 80 and http service public from the firewall GUI.

Now I could access the website locally. So next step is to be able to access it via IP. Went on the router settings and set to port forward 80 to 192.168.0.11.
However I cannot access the website via Public IP by any means. I did a port check and port 80 is open from my ISP. (If you need I can provide you my IP)

I don't understand what is going on it should be working.

Comment: Use a proxy server site.   You cannot access your network via a public IP from inside your network.  So use a proxy sever site to place the request outside of your network.

Comment: Well, that was retarted. Yes it works. Thank you. Could you link me something that explains why I can't do that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning